# Registrar una extensión personalizada twig inyectandole un servicio en Symfony 3 provoca un error

Tags: php, symfony2, twig, symfony3

Estoy usando Symfony 3.1.3 y tengo un servicio llamado "@app.actionmanager" el cual quiero inyectar en una extension Twig propia para mostrar las acciones disponibles (que es de lo que se encarga "@app.actionmanager"). El caso es que cada vez que ejecuto:

```
$> php bin/console cache:clear
```

recibo el error siguiente:

[LogicException]
  Unable to register extension "actionmanager_twig_extension" as extensions have already been initialized.

La declaración de la extensión es:

```
app.twig.actionmanager:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\ActionManagerExtension
    arguments: ["@app.actionmanager"]
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Si elimino la inyección del servicio no existe problema alguno. Si cambio la inyección de dicho servicio por otro (por ejemplo el @service_container) sigo recibiendo el mismo error.

Parece que al inyectar un servicio no se registra la extensión twig hasta que el resto de servicios lo ha hecho y parece que las extensiones twig tuvieran que hacerse en otro momento.

He buscado por internet y nadie más tiene este problema por lo que imagino que debo de estar haciendo algo mal solo que no sé el que.

¿Podéis ayudarme?

Comment: En estos momentos no es posible hacer lo que quieres, por una cuestión de asignación de prioridades a la hora de cargar los elementos. Será a partir de Symfony 3.2 cuando podamos configurar esa prioridad y hacerlo posible. Hasta entonces, solo podemos esperar.

Comment: Has probado inyectar la dependencia usando calls/method en lugar de hacerlo usando el constructor ?

Comment: El problema es el mismo. Tal como comenta Muriano hay que esperar hasta la versión 3.2 donde se podrá configurar prioridades en el DI